# Salvaging screen or keyboard from an old Toshiba T3200 laptop

Tags: laptop, laptop-display

I've got an old Toshiba T3200 laptop from 1987 ([specs here](http://www.toshiba-europe.com/bv/computers/products/notebooks/t3200/product.shtm)) which I haven't been using for years since it's really loud and has a whooping 12 MHz i286 which means no Linux. On top of that the floppy drives are barely functioning and the CMOS battery is dead.

Would it be possible to salvage the screen or the keyboard? Or is everything too proprietary to let anything communicate with the old hardware? I have no idea what kind of cables or connections are used and most articles I've found online has only dealt with much newer laptops.